# SwiftUI List containing Text with word wrap on Mac

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'm having trouble with a List containing Text rows that have text that wraps, on the Mac.

Here's the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var messages = [
        "This is a long piece of text that's going to need to be wrapped to fit into the view.",
        "This is another long piece of text that's going to need to be wrapped to fit into the view."
    ]

    var body: some View {
        List(messages, id: \.self) { message in
            Text(message)
                .lineLimit(nil)
                .border(Color.blue)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)

                // Also tried .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                // which seems more correct, but doesn't wrap the text at all
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

When I run this on iOS, the result is what I'd expect:

[image: Repro-Phone]

On the Mac, however, it seems like the underlying table that SwiftUI is creating isn't adjusting the row heights to fit the wrapped content:

[image: Repro-Mac]

I've reported this as a bug (FB7421021) but asking here in case anyone else struggling with this.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried to put the list in a scrollview?

Comment: I did .. that made the text disappear completely for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is adopted approach from the similar use-case which works for me. Hope it would be useful for somebody else.

```
struct TestWrappedText: View {
    var messages = [
        "This is a long piece of text that's going to need to be wrapped to fit into the view.",
        "This is another long piece of text that's going to need to be wrapped to fit into the view."
    ]

    @State var alignedHeight: [CGFloat] = [0, 0]

    var body: some View {
        List(0 ..< messages.count) { i in
            Text(self.messages[i])
                .border(Color.blue)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                .modifier(ViewHeightKey())
                .onPreferenceChange(ViewHeightKey.self) {
                    if self.alignedHeight[i] != $0 {
                        self.alignedHeight[i] = $0
                    }
                }
                .frame(height: self.alignedHeight[i])
        }
    }
}

struct ViewHeightKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat { 0 }
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

extension ViewHeightKey: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content.background(GeometryReader { proxy in
            Color.clear.preference(key: Self.self, value: proxy.size.height)
        })
    }
}
```